# How do You Delete Commit Data

Tags: git, github, terminal, sass, macos-high-sierra

I added a dmg file to my project, containing all my songs in it. It was over the 100MB GitHub limit. So when I tried to push it, it wouldn't do anything. But it still recognized that it was there even after I deleted it. I tried making a copy out of it but now Atom will crash when I open the project in Atom (GitHubs text editor)

Answer (score 0):

You can revert to the previous commit by using `git reset --hard <commit_hash>`

Find the `<commit_hash>` by using `git log` and taking the long string of numbers and letters after `commit`. It'll look something like this:

```
commit 53f6a9b4219e200a6a0dcf8d367844c1f75e3517 <- this long string is what you want (not the "commit" part though)
Author: author <email@email.com>
Date:   Thu May 17 16:10:39 2018 +0800

    Commit message.
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems like it would work but im getting a 'parse error near \n' even though I did not press enter

Answer (score 0):

As has already been adviced before by @ResetACK, you could reset to the previous commit, but you could also amend the commit where you added the file *if there are other changes on that commit that you would like to keep*. Assuming that the last revision on your current branch is the revision where you added the file, you would do this:

```
git rm --cached mi-dmg-file.dmg
git commit --amend --no-edit
```

If it is not the latest revision on the branch, it can be done this way:

```
git checkout <the-revision-id> # checkout to the revision where we want to remove the file
git rm --cached mi-dmg-file.dmg
git commit --amend --no-edit # at this point, we diverged
git cherry-pick <the-revision-id>..the-branch #cherrypick from original revision to the tip of the branch
git branch -f the-branch # set the branch pointer to this revision now
git push *blahblah arguments* # at this point we can push the branch
```

And now you should be able to push fine.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not the most recent commit

Comment: @Maya If it is not the most recent commit, it is still possible, only that it takes a few more steps. I adjusted the recipe.

Comment: thanks! that will help alot